# Pandas merge two dataframes with one to many relationship

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to merge two pandas DataFrames with one of many relationship.

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['AA', 'BB', 'CC'],
                    'col1': [1, 2, 3],
                    'col2': [1, 2, 3] })

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['AA', 'AA', 'BB'],
                    'col1': [1, 2, 3],
                    'col2': [1, 2, 3] })

df_merged = pd.merge(
                     df1, 
                     df2, 
                     left_on = 'name',
                     right_on = 'name',
                     how = "inner"
                    )
```

Two questions.

1. How do I join the two DataFrames using `pd.merge` without inserting new rows in `df1`? Shape of `df1` needs not change. `name` is unique in `df1`.

For rows with one-to-many relationship, I'd like join the first row from `df2`.

2. When I merge the two DataFrames, it creates new columns - `col1.x, col2.x, col1.y, col2.y`? I'd like only copy of those columns.

Comment: Whats the expected output? give sample output

Answer (score 1):

Use left join and drop duplicates

```
df1.merge(df2, how='left', on='name').drop_duplicates(subset='name',keep='first')
```

Comment: got it. Any thoughts on #2? I'd like to retain only 1 copy of columns. There are two copies `_x`s and `_y`s for columns common between the two DataFrames.

Comment: I seem not to get what you want done. Are you able to give a sample output of the exact thing you want. Happy to help